# onMouseOut events happening in the wrong elements?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On all of our pages, there's an important message displayed across the top.  The message looks like plain red text against a light gray background (same as the rest of the page) when the pages loads.  If the user wants to update it, they can click on it and call the `editMsg` function, which makes it look like a regular text input and a <kbd>Save</kbd> button will appear to the right.

I'm tasked with cancelling the update if the user moves the mouse outside the enclosing div by returning everything to its original appearance.  I tried `onBlur` but I can't seem to get it to do anything!

It seems simple enough, but if I move the mouse outside of the text input but still in the div, it invokes the `cancelMsgChg` function.  I tried several variations of `cancelBubble` (IE) and `stopPropagation` (Firefox) with no luck.  In fact, I don't see why I'd need these if they are in different elements.

The HTML is:

```
<div id="update_message" onMouseOut="cancelMsgChg('onMouseOut');" >
<br />

    <input id="message" onclick="editMsg();" 
     type="text" value="My message"
     style="background:#DDDDDD; color:#DD0000; font-weight:bold; border:0;" />

    <button id="save_message" style="display:none;" 
     class="btn" onclick="return saveHeaderMsg('Save Header Message',  
     document.getElementById('message').value);">Save Message</button>

<br /><br />
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I removed the `onMouseOut` event from the div tag and added an event listener for when the mouse is clicked outside the div:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("click", cancelMsgChg('click'), false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  // IE
  document.attachEvent("onclick", cancelMsgChg('onclick'), false); 
}

function cancelMsgChg(e) {
      
  console.log ("in cancelMsgChg");

  // In Internet Explorer you should use the global variable `event`  
  e = e || event; 

  // In Internet Explorer you need `srcElement`
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  var id = target.id;
  
  console.log ("id = " + id);
  
  if ( id != "update_message" ) {
    //reset everything
  }
}
```

But I get a "target is undefined" error.  So... `e` is not defined at all?

Comment: _I'm tasked with cancelling the update if the user moves the mouse outside the enclosing div by returning everything to its original appearance._ This sounds like a usability nightmare. Why not a cancel button next to the save button?

Comment: Why not try JQuery? I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: I've requested jQuery but it hasn't been approved yet.  I have a cancel button all coded up and it works great, but that's apparently not what they want.  I have to use IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is two fold. One is that mousing over an inner element triggers mouseout on the parent, and second is leaving the inner element is triggering a mouseout on that element that bubbles to the parent.

To get around this you need to examine the target of the event and look at where the mouse is going, and only run your code if the mouseout if from your parent element and is to something outside of your parent. Here's a simple [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/HcFtm/1/):

```
<div class="outer" onmouseout="mouseout(event)">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

function mouseout(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(event.relatedTarget);
  console.log("mouseout!");
}
```

In the fiddle, I have an outer div with the onmouseout handler defined inline. If you watch the console, you'll see that if you mouse in to the outer div and then back out, the mouseout event will fire. However, if you move the mouse into the outer div, and then into the inner div, you will also get a mouseout event. And finally, if you move out of the inner div (but still in the outer div) you will get another mouseout event!

Comment: I KNEW this was supposed to be easy!  Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

On blur will do nothing for you since you are not using any form elements (input, select, textarea).

The mouseOut event is triggered even if the mouse is moved into one of the elements inside of the div.  You could check where the mouse is headed when the mouseOut event is triggered to see if it is entering one of those enclosed divs. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html for more info.